# StartService FAILED 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: windows-10, launch4j

> [SC] StartService FAILED 1053:
>
> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion.

I have tried solution mentioned in various discussion like adding `servicesPipeTimeout` with some bigger timeout value but it is not working.

I have an exe , which I am able to launch independently, but when try to start it as windows service its giving the above mentioned error. The problem is, its blind error without any hint.

Answer (score 6):

Check your event viewer for exceptions from this service. This worked for me.

Comment: there is nothing in event viewer regarding this.

Answer (score -5):

Open cmd as administrator at yourService.exe directory and run yourService.exe -install.
This worked for me :)